# Big O notation - why is O(n^2/4) = O(n^2)

Tags: big-o

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851387/1920161) Marcelo Cantos has replied:

> O((n/2 + 1)*(n/2)) = O(n<sup>2</sup>/4 + n/2) = O(n<sup>2</sup>/4) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Up to

> O(n<sup>2</sup>/4) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

I can understand, but why is the dividing by 4 ignored (or the multiplying by 1/4)?

Comment: Because 4 is much less than N.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not programming. Use the CS stackexchange site.

Comment: In "big O" computations you ignore all constant multipliers and only concern yourself with the power of N.  (Yes, it can be kind of silly in some cases but makes sense when N is very large.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant multipliers are ignored when dealing with complexity. Whether a step in an algorithm is 2, 4, or 1000 times as long as a step in another algorithm is irrelevant when all we care about is the number of steps involved.

Comment: +1, and the reason why we ignore the constants and multipliers is, because they are unimportant compared to the exponent.